# Remove array in array using splice issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have and array added_collections and current state is:

```
    added_collections
(2) [Array(2), Array(1)]
0: Array(2)
0: []
1: [{…}]
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
1: [Array(10)]
length: 2
```

I need to remove an product from collection so I write:

```
added_collections[0][1].splice(0, 1);
```

so the result I expect to get is :

```
added_collections
(2) [Array(2), Array(1)]
0: Array(2)
0: []
1: []
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
1: [Array(10)]
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

but instead that I get:

```
(2) [Array(2), Array(1)]
0: Array(0)
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
1: [Array(10)]
length: 2
```

Why its two empty arrays are merged?

When I follow steps in browser console everything is fine but when I run the same code to execute its not the same results and seems that 2 empty arrays missing

UPDATE:
this is the full code of added_collection[0]:

```
'[[[],[{"id":32620843270280,"product_id":4632299831432,"title":"3 / red","price":"249.00","sku":"DM-03-red-3","position":1,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"0.00","fulfillment_service":"manual"}]]]'
```

and I run js code:

```
let coll_no = 0;
    let page_no = 1;
    let product_no = 0;

    added_collections[coll_no][page_no].splice(product_no, 1);
```

Comment: This is related to how you created the array.  Without the minimal code it's impossible to help you. Objects and array in JavaScript use references

Comment: but its the same code that I test manually

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I update with code

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

```js
const collection = [
  [
    [],
    [{
      "id": 32620843270280,
      "product_id": 4632299831432,
      "title": "3 / red",
      "price": "249.00",
      "sku": "DM-03-red-3",
      "position": 1,
      "inventory_policy": "deny",
      "compare_at_price": "0.00",
      "fulfillment_service": "manual"
    }]
  ]
]

collection[0][1].splice(0, 1)
console.log(collection)
```

Comment: I create added_collections like var added_collections = new Array();